# Example data within a class - Good or bad practise?

Tags: java

Is it a good idea to write example data within a class which can be instantiated?

In the following example, i am using some static var's which are used to get direct access to some Contacts via:

```
Contact.contact101()
...
```

I am using this example data definition within a test and don't want to write a kind of util class which contains all the example data.

```
package com.example.webdriver.util.builder.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import com.example.webdriver.util.builder.LocalStorageBuilder;
import com.example.webdriver.util.builder.enumaration.UserStatus;

public class Contact {

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("puid")
    private Long principleUserId;
    @SerializedName("cuid")
    private Long contactUserId;
    @SerializedName("v")
    private int visible;
    @SerializedName("ustat")
    private String userStatus;
    @SerializedName("ats")
    private Long addedTimeStamp;

    private static Contact contact101;
    private static Contact contact102;
    private static Contact contact305;
    private static Contact contact302;
    private static Contact contact301;
    private static Contact contact382;


    public Contact() {
        this.id = LocalStorageBuilder.getContactIdCounter();
        this.principleUserId = LocalStorageBuilder.principalUserId;
        this.contactUserId = 301L;
        this.visible = 1;
        this.userStatus = String.valueOf(UserStatus.ONLINE.getUserStatus());
        this.addedTimeStamp = 1410168552386L;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getPrincipleUserId() {
        return principleUserId;
    }

    public void setPrincipleUserId(Long principleUserId) {
        this.principleUserId = principleUserId;
    }

    public int getVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        if (visible) {
            this.visible = 1;
        } else {
            this.visible = 0;
        }
    }

    public String getUserStatus() {
        return userStatus;
    }

    public void setUserStatus(UserStatus userStatus) {
        this.userStatus = String.valueOf(userStatus.getUserStatus());
    }

    public Long getAddedTimeStamp() {
        return addedTimeStamp;
    }

    public void setAddedTimeStamp(Long addedTimeStamp) {
        this.addedTimeStamp = addedTimeStamp;
    }

    public Long getContactUserId() {
        return contactUserId;
    }

    public void setContactUserId(Long contactUserId) {
        this.contactUserId = contactUserId;
    }


    // Example data

    public static Contact contact102() {
        if (contact102 == null) {
            contact102 = createContact(102L);
        }
        contact102.setPrincipleUserId(LocalStorageBuilder.principalUserId);
        return contact102;
    }

    public static Contact contact302() {
        if (contact302 == null) {
            contact302 = createContact(302L);
        }
        contact302.setPrincipleUserId(LocalStorageBuilder.principalUserId);
        return contact302;
    }

    public static Contact contact305() {
        if (contact305 == null) {
            contact305 = createContact(305L);
        }
        contact305.setPrincipleUserId(LocalStorageBuilder.principalUserId);
        return contactAVG305;
    }


    private static Contact createContact(Long contactUserId) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setContactUserId(contactUserId);
        contact.setPrincipleUserId(LocalStorageBuilder.principalUserId);
        contact.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ONLINE);
        contact.setAddedTimeStamp(1410168552386L);
        contact.setVisible(true);
        return contact;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Separate it into a factory specifically used for your tests.

Comment: Being afraid to write one more class is mostly wrong. Be more afraid of adding members to a class.

Answer (score 2):

No, use some kind of factory instead.

There are various terms around the internet, `ObjectMother` is one, although I prefer `TestDataFactory`.

```
public class TestDataFactory {
    private static Contact createContact(Long contactUserId) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setContactUserId(contactUserId);
        contact.setPrincipleUserId(LocalStorageBuilder.principalUserId);
        contact.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ONLINE);
        contact.setAddedTimeStamp(1410168552386L);
        contact.setVisible(true);
        return contact;
    }
}
```

The advantage is that this can live in your `test` sources, not poluting your domain objects with test code.

Answer (score 1):

This makes re factoring tough and as per class definition, this is not valid here.

The correct place is to create another class named `TestDataHelper` and create a method named `getContacts` and return list of `Contact` objects.

Concerns should always be separated. This is how Java works !